# Is there a way to get the SCN without querying the database?

Tags: oracle, ojdbc

Today, to get the SCN of the database, we query v$database. Is this the only way to get the database's SCN? Is there any API that exposes this information as part of a connection's metadata, etc?

Comment: SCN = System Change Number ?

Comment: Yes, SCN = System Change Number.

Comment: There's also the PL/SQL function `DBMS_FLASHBACK.GET_SYSTEM_CHANGE_NUMBER`.  But like almost all of the connection metadata, it must eventually come from a query anyway.  What's your real problem - are you trying to avoid extra queries, are you trying to avoid granting privileges to `v$database`, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

The System Change Number (SCN) is extremely related to the inner details of an Oracle instance; even the function that take a TIMESTAMP and convert it to an SCN (`TIMESTAMP_TO_SCN`) is limited to a brief period of time per [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TIMESTAMP_TO_SCN.html#GUID-58796E1A-9943-4966-96E6-78B636BD2859).  Summary: the SCN is updated frequently; and there are several things that affect the update period; commits, Undo management, workload, etc.  So as Jon Heller points out in his comment, there is no way to get close to a real SCN without asking Oracle for it.